# ASP.net refreshing control

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a string that is constantly being updated inside a class. On my webpage, I have a textbox that displays the said string. Now, is there a way to `refresh` the contents of the textbox without having to reload the page?

Comment: you can use update panel(partial post back) or a webmethod to get new content and update it

Comment: to answer your question yes.

Comment: Yes you could use ajax for ashynchronous callbacks. Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before posting any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using the Ajax framework, use the following code in your aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3600" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<!-- Here your TextBox -->
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1"
        EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this in your code behind:

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

A second option would be using a [client callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

A third option would be to use [ASP.net SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's how web pages work. If you want new content, you must load it, request it. 
What you can do is a partial reload with an `UpdatePanel` and a `Timer`.

Comment: Why not? Why the downvote?

Comment: Because to say **no** is wrong. There are literally hundreds of ways to do this.

Comment: "Without having to reload", I'd say "no", because you cannot push the update from the server. 
You will always have to "reload", even if it is a partial AJAX reload, as I write in my answer.

Comment: I am not arguing against you, Liam. We have a communication problem. All the hundreds of solutions do some kind of reload.

Comment: Ok, let me calm down. My issue with your answer is it's misleading to say no and it doesn't contain enough detail. That said this is a very bad question as it is far too broad. But I still think the -1 is deserved I'm afraid.

Comment: Also I can't actually remove my -1 anymore....I was just going to give you the benefit of the doubt, oh well.

Comment: I understand what you mean. :-)

Comment: There is SignalR a complete .net library for the purpose of pushing server updates to the client.

Comment: +1. It's right. no request(load), no new content.